# How do I get matcher.find while loop to write to text file? java

Tags: java, filewriter

I'm using a while(matcher.find()) loop to write certain substrings to a file.  I get a list of the matched strings occurring in the file in my System.out console just fine, but when I try to use FileWriter to write to a text file, I only get the very last string in the loop written.  I've scoured stackoverflow for similar problems (and it lives up to its name), I couldn't find anything that helped me.  And just to clarify this isn't being run on the EDT.  Can anyone explain where to look for the problem?

```
try {
    String writeThis = inputId1 + count + inputId2 + link + inputId3;
    newerFile = new FileWriter(writePath);
    //this is only writing the last line from the while(matched.find()) loop
    newerFile.write(writeThis);
    newerFile.close();
    //it prints to console just fine!  Why won't it print to a file?
    System.out.println(count + " " + show + " " + link); 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Logger.getLogger(Frame1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    } finally {
        try {
            newerFile.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Logger.getLogger(Frame1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);

            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick fix:

change

```
newerFile = new FileWriter(writePath);
```

to

```
newerFile = new FileWriter(writePath, true);
```

This uses the [`FileWriter(String fileName, boolean append)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) constructor.

---

Better fix:

create the `FileWriter` outside of the `while(matcher.find())` loop and close it afterwards (or use it as a `try with resources` initilzation).

the code would be something like:

```
try (FileWriter newerFile = new FileWriter(writePath)) {
   while (matcher.find()) {
      newerFile.write(matcher.group());
   }
} ...
```

Comment: Ah yes, I was creating the FileWriter within the loop and with no append switch lol... thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You should not create an instance of `FileWriter` every loop iteration. You need to leave the usage of method `write()` there and init `FileWriter` before loop and close it after loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please check as follows:

FileWriter newerFile = new FileWriter(writePath);
while(matcher.find())
{
xxxxx
try {
    String writeThis = inputId1 + count + inputId2 + link + inputId3;

    //this is only writing the last line from the while(matched.find()) loop
    newerFile.write(writeThis);
    newerFile.flush();
    //it prints to console just fine!  Why won't it print to a file?
    System.out.println(count + " " + show + " " + link); 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Logger.getLogger(Frame1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    } finally {
        try {
            newerFile.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Logger.getLogger(Frame1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);

            }
    }
}
}
```